# How do I get a value from a callback function to the outside scope?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, callback

I have a function `getHighScores` which I want to go into a JSON file and get score objects for a given `game`, sort them, and return the top `amount` of them.

This is my (broken) code:

```
function getHighScores(game, amount) {
    var highScores = null;
    fs.readFile('scores.json', 'utf8', function (error, data) {
        var scoresObj = JSON.parse(data);
        var gameScores = scoresObj.games[game];
        sortedScores = gameScores.sort(compareScoreObjects);
        highScores = sortedScores.slice(0, amount);
    });
    return highScores;
}

console.log(getHighScores('snake', 10));
```

This is logging `null`, because `highScores` cannot be accessed within the scope of the callback function for `fs.readFile`.

Is there any way to do this while maintaining the logic of my code - where I can simply have `getHighScores` return the data? If not, how should I be thinking about this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is you're using readFile, which is an asynchronous method. Meaning by the time this method resolves, highScores is already returned.

Checkout the readFileSync method (https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options) which is a synchronous version of readFile.

You can then change your code as follows.

```
function getHighScores(game, amount) {
  var scoresObj = fs.readFileSync('scores.json', 'utf8');
  var parsedScoresObj = JSON.parse(data);
  var gameScores = parsedScoresObj.games[game];
  var sortedScores = gameScores.sort(compareScoreObjects);
  var highScores = sortedScores.slice(0, amount);
  return highScores;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From what I have read, fs.readfile is async. So highScores is returning immediately instead of wating to read the file. You could change the code to be synchronous.

```
function getHighScores(game, amount) {
var highScores = null;
var data = fs.readFileSync('scores.json', 'utf8')
var scoresObj = JSON.parse(data);
var gameScores = scoresObj.games[game];
sortedScores = gameScores.sort(compareScoreObjects);
highScores = sortedScores.slice(0, amount);
return highScores;
}

console.log(getHighScores('snake', 10));
```

If you want to keep it asynchronous though then you should check this link

[How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)